# Stack overflow exception in compojure web project

Tags: web-applications, clojure, compojure

I've been playing around with clojure and have been using it to build a simple little audio player. The strange thing is that sometimes, maybe one out of twenty, when contacting the server I will get the following error:

```
2010-04-20 15:33:20.963::WARN:  Error for /control
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.core$seq__4245.invoke(core.clj:105)
    at clojure.core$filter__5084$fn__5086.invoke(core.clj:1794)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.core$seq__4245.invoke(core.clj:105)
    at clojure.core$filter__5084$fn__5086.invoke(core.clj:1794)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.core$seq__4245.invoke(core.clj:105)
    at clojure.core$filter__5084$fn__5086.invoke(core.clj:1794)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.core$seq__4245.invoke(core.clj:105)
    at clojure.core$filter__5084$fn__5086.invoke(core.clj:1794)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:440)
        ...
```

If I do it right after again it always works. So it appears to be related to timing or something. The code in question is:

```
(defn add-track [t]
  (common/ref-add tracks t))

(defn add-collection [coll]
  (doseq [track coll] (add-track track)))
```

and

```
(defn ref-add [ref value]
  (dosync (ref-set ref (conj @ref value))))
```

where coll is extracted from this function:

```
(defn tracks-by-album [album]
  (sort sort-tracks (filter #(= (:album %) album) @tracks)))
```

which uses:

```
(defn get-album-from-track [track]
  (seq/find-first #(= (:album track) (:name %)) @albums))

(defn sort-tracks [track1 track2]
  (cond (= (:album track1) (:album track2))
    (cond (and (:album-track track1) (:album-track track2))
      (< (:album-track track1) (:album-track track2))
      :else 0)
    :else
     (> (:year (get-album-from-track track1)) (:year (get-album-from-track track2)))))
```

it gets called more or less directly from the request I get in:

```
(when-handle-command cmd params (audio/tracks-by-album decoded-name))

(defn when-handle-command [cmd params data]
  (println (str "handling command:" cmd))
    ....)
```

I never get the handling command in my log, so it must die when it does the tracks-by-album.

so it does appear to be the tracks-by-album function from the stack trace. I just don't see why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I say that it's tracks-by-album because it's the only function (including it's children) that does filter, as can be seen in the trace.

All the source code is available at: http://code.google.com/p/mucomp/. It's my little hobby project to learn clojure and so far it's quite buggy (this is just one bug :)) so I havn't really liked to tell too many people about it yet :)

Comment: You say "(...) so it does appear to be the tracks-by-album function from the stack trace", but that function does not feature in (the part of) the stack trace you've posted. Was there more error output? Also, could you show us sort-tracks and any places tracks-by-album gets called from? (Or maybe you could pick those which seem the most relevant if there's too many to post them all.)

Comment: I updated the post with some more code. Also the stack trace just continues like that snippet I posted of it. There is no more interesting information sadly ;-)

Comment: one more thing I'd like to add is that tracks is a ref to a list of about 2300 elements (structs with stuff like name, filename etc.)

Comment: Took me a while to understand that "Stack overflow" is not a reference to this site ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question on the clojure mailing list. And it appears that the answer is that filter returns a lazy seq, and when you chain those, you'll end in a stack overflow at some point. One can force the generation of the sequence using doall.